# Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy Flask API + NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flask, cors, flask-cors

I have a problem between frontend backend and Flask API.

To execute my project I do `npm start. This will run the ReactJs frontend dev server on port 3000.

> In package.json

I added the following `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",`

Next, I do

> cd backend && python server.py after activating my venv

This will run the Flask API on port 5000

The Flask API has this route

```
from flask_cors import cross_origin
# File download Link
@app.route('/filePath', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def get_path():
    data = request.get_json()["path"]
    storage.child(f"files/{data}").download(f"files/Resume.pdf")
    return "Success.."
```

Finally, in another shell I do

> cd backend && node server.js running on port 8080

Which has the following post

```
app.post('/insert', async (req, response) => {
    const mobile_number = req.body.college_name
    const name = req.body.college_name
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/details').then(async (res) => {
        const recruit = new RecruitModel({
            mobile_number:res.data.mobile_number, name:res.data.name,
            });
        await recruit.save()
        response.send("inserted data")
      });
});
```

Here is where the error happens in the frontend.

```
const uploadFiles = (file) => {
      //
      if (!file) return;
      if (!initialData) return null;
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${file.name}`);
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
  
      uploadTask.on(
        "state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          const prog = Math.round(
            (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
          );
          setProgress(prog);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error),
        () => {
          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async () => {
            console.log(file.name);
            await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/filePath', {
              'path': file.name
            }).then(() => console.log(file.name));
            update();
          });
        }
      );
    };
```

In await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/filePath' I'm assuming.

I get the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/insert' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'http://localhost:5000' that is not equal to the supplied origin

I thought using flask-cors would fix this so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

I'm really struggling on this error, Any suggestions please?

**EDIT**

```
  const addRecruit = () => {
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/insert", {
          college_name:initialData.college_name,
          email:initialData.email, 
          mobile_number:initialData.mobile_number, name:initialData.name
    });
  }
```

This is where the issue is happening. Because the data is being fetched between Flask and ReactJs but this /insert is in server.js

Comment: Just remove the http://localhost:5000/ from the url in axios. It will be converted to `axios.post('/filePath)'`.

Comment: @TirthTrivedi Still the same thing.. I know where the error is but Idk what to do about it. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EDIT made things clear, the issue isn't to do with your Flask api. You need to enable cors in server.js

I'm assuming you had this setup before,

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Do this instead

```
const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:3000', 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Don't forget to `npm i cors`

Comment: Will test this and let you know